# Need MySQL key indexed?

Tags: mysql

Let say i have two tables,

for the sake of question, let's assume that they are two tables called `customers` and `cars`.

```
Customers
id   name    age

Cars
id   customer_id  brand_id   engine    cc
```

Do we need to index customer_id? Does it give any advantage?

Comment: Like always - "it depends". It depends on your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like to highlight that on `InnoDB`, index automatically created on foreign key columns.
see [innodb-foreign-key-constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

in your case `customer_id` if the foreign key constraint is applied.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, you probably want to join the customers table, you need to put a index on customer_id so the lookup can be done faster.

But like said in the comments, it depends, if you're not going to join the customers table (or do a WHERE / GROUP BY / ORDER BY etc. on it) and purely use it do display the id, it is not necassery.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application business logic and how you will query the base, having an index on customer_id will give you a huge advantage on queries like

```
select * from customers join cars on customer_id = customers.id -- list all customers with their associated cars
```

Or even

```
select * from cars where customer_id = 2 -- list all cars for user 2
```

More generally, it is always a good idea to index foreign key constraints.